# Detect whether there is a qws server running

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtgui, qtembedded

In order to properly launch a little Qt app on an embedded system, I need a reliable way to find out whether a Qt QWS server is already running.

Otherwise I'd need to supply the `-qws`option to the app to run the server itself. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: What is wrong about reading the process table and the passed options?

Comment: @FinalContest What's wrong about posting a proper answer? You might even get upvoted :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not personally think this is the best way, but I also do not think there is a simpler way, unfortunately. Fwiw, I do not understand why this question got downvoted. Perhaps someone thought it is too short or so. I compensated that now. :)

Comment: @FinalContest Thanks. No offense take, none intended. Happy hacking on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I settled for:

The QWS server uses to socket to talk to its clients. I test for the existence of this socket.

I also test whether the server actually has the socked open in order to avoid falling for orphaned sockets left over after a QWS server crash. This is done using `lsof` (list open files) on the socket. If the server is running, the list will not be empty and `lsof` will return `true`. If the server is not running, `lsof` will return `false`.

On my system the socket was located in `/tmp/qtembedded-0/QtEmbedded-0`

So here is the bash code:

```
QWSSOCK=/tmp/qtembedded-0/QtEmbedded-0

if [ ! -S $QWSSOCK ] ; then
    echo "No socket $QWSSOCK"
    QWSOPT=-qws
elif lsof $QWSSOCK ; then
    echo "Server running on $QWSSOCK"
    QWSOPT=
else
    echo "No server on $QWSSOCK"
    QWSOPT=-qws
fi
```

After this I can run my Qt app using the `$QWSOPT` variable:

```
app $QWSOPT
```

Comment: The directory is still there, even when the server stops. So, this method is not very reliable

Comment: @BЈовић Yes, the directory, and even the socket may remain if the server crahsed. That's why the code uses the `lsof`command to see if the server actually has the socked open. This make the method very reliable.

Comment: doh sorry. Somehow I missed `lsof`

Answer (score 1):

The only quick workaround coming to mind is this:

```
ps aux | grep "\-qws"
```

and check if that returns anything. Other than that, I think you should obsolete qws in your project as it is a relatively old and broken concept with today's standards.

Comment: Unfortuately, this is no reliable, as Qt programs may run a QWS servers without having the `-qws` option on their command line. Also, the string might be part of some other command line element.

Comment: @Ber: to the former, yes, if the QApplication is constructed with that type. I am not sure you can detect that without some additional code, i.e. config, IPC, etc. As for the latter, that is true theoretically, but I am yet to find a case where that happens in the practice. ;-)